# CORS error in Typescript/NodeJS | don't recognize server config

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, google-signin

i've been searching data to resolve this but it's been more than a week and don't understand why this didn't work.

i'm trying to do a google login in react 18. If i hard-code Browser and disable CORS, it works perfectly, but instead in normal browser i got this:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fauth%2Fworker%2Fcallback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&client_id=1xxxxxxxxxxxx-dn5o5nsgkeb69itt29dqsqobiova6ogi.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3001/auth/worker') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

when console.log of res and req, the config seems normal, exact this code:

this is app.ts

```
app.use(cors({origin: true))
app.use((_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
  next();
});
```

in back route /auth/worker i have this config

```
    const loginGoogle = express.Router();
loginGoogle.use(passport.initialize())

loginGoogle.use(session({
    secret: SECRET_KEY,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
loginGoogle.post("/worker", passportGoogleWorker.authenticate("google", {scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]}), (req: any, _res: any) => {
    const {code} = req.query
    console.log("code", code)
    return (code)  
})
```

const code returns correct information in hardcoded browser, instead in normal browser doesn't even run the console.log(code)

NOTE: i tried origin: '*' and method get instead post, but don't work

Comment: try to allow one origin > Enable CORS for a Single Route https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors , add the google domain, if you want; you can add multiples origin = [domain, domain2, domain3]

Comment: did you added `credentials: true` in your cors options

Comment: Thanks for comment, i tried both but nothing works